# Перемещение Line по canvas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать плавное перемещение Line по canvas при помощи мыши, как не пробовал нормальное перемещение организовать не удалось.

```
private bool _isAttached = false;          
private FrameworkElement _attachedElement; 
private Point _clickPoint;

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   canvas.MouseMove += MainCanvasOnMouseMove;               
}

// создание линии
 private void ButtonCreateLine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     Line line =  new Line()
            {
                X1 = 200,
                X2 = 300,
                Y1 = 200,
                Y2 = 300,
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = defaultStrokeThickness
            };

            line.MouseLeftButtonUp += LineOnMouseLeftButtonUp;
            line.MouseLeftButtonDown += LineOnMouseLeftButtonDown;

            canvas.Children.Add(line);

}

// отпускаем левую мышь
 private void LineOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
     _isAttached = false;
}

// зажимаем левую мышь
private void LineOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
{
            _clickPoint = mouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement);
            _attachedElement = sender as FrameworkElement;

            _isAttached = true;
}

// движение мыши по канвасу
private void MainCanvasOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
            if (_isAttached && _attachedElement != null && _clickPoint.X <= canvas.Width)
            {
                if(_attachedElement.GetType() == typeof(Line))
                {

                    //тут много что пробовал, так и не получилось сделать грамотное перемещение
                   
                    Line line = (Line)_attachedElement;

                    line.X1 += mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(canvas).X - _clickPoint.X;
                    line.X2 += mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(canvas).X - _clickPoint.X;

                    line.Y1 += mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(canvas).Y - _clickPoint.Y;
                    line.Y2 += mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(canvas).Y - _clickPoint.Y;

                   
                }

            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько замечаний:

1. Дельту для перемещения объекта нужно считать не от координат первичного нажатия на линию `_clickPoint`, а от предыдущего положения курсора (`_lastPos`).
2. Граничное условие `_clickPoint.X <= canvas.Width` лучше изменить на `<= canvas.ActualWidth`, т.к. выравнивание canvas может быть задано по разному. В данном случае, это условие не нужно, ведь событие происходит в рамках canvas.
3. Событие `ButtonUp` правильно вешать на canvas, а не линию, т.к. в момент отпускания кнопки курсор может быть не на линии.

Пример:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool _isAttached = false;
    private FrameworkElement _attachedElement;
    private Point _lastPos;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        canvas.MouseMove += MainCanvasOnMouseMove;
        canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp += MainCanvasOnLeftButtonUp;
    }

    // создание линии
    private void ButtonCreateLine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Line line = new Line()
        {
            X1 = 200,
            X2 = 300,
            Y1 = 200,
            Y2 = 300,
            Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black,
            StrokeThickness = 5
        };
            
        line.MouseLeftButtonDown += LineOnMouseLeftButtonDown;

        canvas.Children.Add(line);
    }

    // отпускаем левую мышь
    private void MainCanvasOnLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        _isAttached = false;
    }

    // зажимаем левую мышь
    private void LineOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        _lastPos = mouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement);
        _attachedElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        _isAttached = true;
    }

    // движение мыши по канвасу
    private void MainCanvasOnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        Point currentPos = mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(sender as FrameworkElement);
            
        if (_isAttached && _attachedElement != null)
        {
            if (_attachedElement.GetType() == typeof(Line))
            {
                Line line = (Line)_attachedElement;

                line.X1 += currentPos.X - _lastPos.X;
                line.X2 += currentPos.X - _lastPos.X;

                line.Y1 += currentPos.Y - _lastPos.Y;
                line.Y2 += currentPos.Y - _lastPos.Y;

                _lastPos.X = currentPos.X;
                _lastPos.Y = currentPos.Y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Я обычно разделяю расчет дельты и перерисовку объекта, чтобы перерисовка была с заданной частотой.

Comment: Да, и условие `_attachedElement != null` - лишнее, т.к. при _isAttached = true объект имеется

Comment: " Событие ButtonUp правильно вешать на canvas, а не линию, т.к. в момент отпускания кнопки курсор может быть не на линии. "  Наоборот в момент отпускания курсор всегда находиться на линии, так как линия всегда догоняет курсор(перерисовывается по координатам на которых находиться курсор)  пока зажата левая кнопка мыши, куда бы он не переместился . Моя основная проблема в том, что когда курсор выходит за пределы линии перемещение не работает.

Comment: Не соглашусь с Вами. Оставьте обработчик на линии. После этого попробуйте быстро перетащить линию и отпустить в процессе - линия останется прилипшей к курсору. Как раз потому, что линия догоняет курсор, и в момент, когда она отстает, событие поймает только canvas.